# Getting entries excluding the first

Tags: entries, loop

I'm trying to set up having the first entry pull in and then later down the page pull in the remaining posts (as I need to break the loop with other content). I'm a little unsure how to set up pulling in the 'Not firstEntry' for the second part. This is what I'm working with:

```
{% paginate craft.entries.section('blog').limit(1) as entriesOnPage %}
{% for entry in entriesOnPage %}
{% set firstEntry = craft.entries.section('blog').order('postDate desc').one() %}

{% if entry.id == firstEntry.id and craft.request.getPageNum() == 1 %}
//output first entry
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}

// DO OTHER STUFF

{% paginate craft.entries.section('blog').limit(12) as entriesOnPage %}
{% for entry in entriesOnPage %}

//OUTPUT 12 Entries not including the first

{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Measure twice, cut once" goes the saying... (Kind of the opposite here, but the same principle!) - Fetch your data once, then cut it up how you like using Twig filters. In your case you can fetch the first item from an array with `[0]` and then slice off that same entry from the start of the same array with `|slice(1)` like this:

```
{% paginate craft.entries.section('blog').order('postDate desc').limit(13) as entriesOnPage %}

{% set firstEntry = entriesOnPage[0] %}
{% set theRest = entriesOnPage|slice(1) %}

{# ======================================================================= #}

<h1>{{ firstEntry.title }}</h1>

{% for entry in theRest %}
    {# OUTPUT 12 Entries not including the first #}
    <h2>{{ entry.title }}</h2>
{% endfor %}
```